# Multiple MySQL SELECTS in one statement

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications

I am building a web app that uses a system similar to twitter (Follow someone and that users ID is added to your profile and when you view your timeline you see all of your follows). I am trying to select multiple fields of data in one statement with different conditions. i.e. `SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE id='I want to have multiple IDs for the query to select.'`. Each user is different so I am wondering do I just separate them by commas or something? I have no idea. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you give your table structure and your query so far?

Comment: this is actually one select statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you mean correctly, you're looking for the [`IN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) keyword that will match any listed id;

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE id IN (1,7,12,44,36);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3)"

For example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IN LIST function like `SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,.....)`

Answer (score 0):

as stated, you are looking for the `IN` clause... however, I think this is really a `JOIN` to your 'friends' table instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE ID IN (1,2,3, ...)
```